# sed or awk: replace \n from selected multiple lines

Tags: awk, sed

I have a text file as below

```
jhasdh jkhsd
lahs dkjh j

<table>
<colgroup>
<col style="width: 100%" />
</colgroup>
<tbody>
<tr class="odd">
<td><p><span class="c2">sample text</span></p>
<p><span class="c2">sample text3</span></p>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>


lajslkdjl 

;kjksalkd j

;kasdl kj


<table>
<colgroup>
<col style="width: 100%" />
</colgroup>
<tbody>
<tr class="odd">
<td><p><span class="c2">sample text223</span></p>
<p><span class="c2">sample 2332text3</span></p>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>

jashdkjh

jashdjkh


jskdhkj
```

Now i want the entire `<table> .mutiple lines her.. </table>` to be in one line. i.e

```
jhasdh jkhsd
lahs dkjh j

<table><colgroup><col style="width: 100%" /></colgroup><tbody><tr class="odd"><td><p><span class="c2">sample text</span></p><p><span class="c2">sample text3</span></p></td></tr></tbody></table>


lajslkdjl 

;kjksalkd j

;kasdl kj


<table><colgroup><col style="width: 100%" /></colgroup><tbody><tr class="odd"><td><p><span class="c2">sample text223</span></p><p><span class="c2">sample 2332text3</span></p></td></tr></tbody></table>

jashdkjh

jashdjkh


jskdhkj
```

I can do this in sublime text as follows

find: `(?s)(<table>(?:(?!<table>).)*?</table>)`

then all the `<table> ... </table>` are selected

then find `\n` and replace with `""` (blank) in the `selection`

But i want to do it using sed or awk

how can i do it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
awk '/<table>/{ORS=""} /<\/table>/{ORS=RS} 1' file
```

for each line:

- if `<table>` is found, set **O**utput **R**ecord **S**eparator to empty string (`""`),
- if `</table>` is found, restore ORS,
- print.

see this [online demo](https://ideone.com/FotzMa).

note that this might work for your sample but obviously won't work for all `table` elements. see [why parsing HTML using regex is a bad practice](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/10248678).

Answer (score 0):

if your data in 'd' file try gnu sed,

```
sed -E '/<table>/{:a N;/.*\n<\/table>/!ba;s/\n//g;} ' d
```